# How to manage huge data inside mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have an issue with huge data on my table.

Let suppose i have a table name **employee_details** and columns are

```
Emp-name |  Emp-email | Emp-mobile | Emp-designation | Emp-salary
```

Suppose i have 1,00000 rows inside it. Then how should i structure table for best performance.

Comment: What company is this? Only a handful of organizations have over a million employees, and most of them are governments.

Comment: And any company that large should be able to afford a better database than MySQL.

Comment: I took employe  as example to explain the problem. Can we use different table name for different data , for example: if employee name starts with "A" then it will be inserted in table A,  if employee name starts with "B" then it will be inserted in table B, there would be total 26 table inside the database. But problem will occur in fetching the records from database.

Comment: You can do that with partitioned tables.

Comment: The optimal solution depends on all the queries you want to execute. The best performance for situation 1 may affect other queries you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

100000 rows are not a big deal for Mysql. They are designed to handle millions of rows. Make sure your datatypes and indexes are setup properly and you should be good.